# Selecting rows that fulfills the criteria of having other rows within a given difference of a variable in the same group

Tags: r

I've got a dataset of many individuals("ID") with body weight measurement ("BW")at random time points("time") spanning over 15 years.

```
Example:

ID=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
Time=c("2015/1/1","2015/3/1","2016/1/1","2016/3/1","2017/1/1","2018/5/1","2012/1/1","2017/5/1","2019/4/1","2020/4/1","2019/10/1","2020/1/1","2020/4/1")
BW=rnorm(13,mean=75)
df<-data.frame(ID,Time,BW)

   ID      Time       BW
1   1  2015/1/1 75.01736
2   1  2015/3/1 75.44717
3   1  2016/1/1 73.09934
4   1  2016/3/1 74.79920
5   1  2017/1/1 74.70097
6   1  2018/5/1 74.23496
7   2  2012/1/1 73.57179
8   2  2017/5/1 74.50970
9   2  2019/4/1 74.43412
10  2  2020/4/1 75.02952
11  3 2019/10/1 76.41390
12  3  2020/1/1 75.79827
13  3  2020/4/1 74.46035
```

What I'm trying to filter are **IDs with measurements that has one within 12+/- 3 months prior to this measurement and one after**. ie. one bodyweight at 0yr+/-3months one at 1yr one at 2yr+/-3months. In this case, only rows 3 to 5 fulfill the criteria.

And in all "individuals" that fulfills such criteria, I would like choose the measurement that has **the most data points within this +/- 15 months range**. The example desired output may look like:

```
   ID      Time       BW Fulfill Counts
1   1  2015/1/1 75.01736       0      4
2   1  2015/3/1 75.44717       0      4
3   1  2016/1/1 73.09934       1      5
4   1  2016/3/1 74.79920       1      5
5   1  2017/1/1 74.70097       1      3
6   1  2018/5/1 74.23496       0      2
7   2  2012/1/1 73.57179       0      1
8   2  2017/5/1 74.50970       0      1
9   2  2019/4/1 74.43412       0      2
10  2  2020/4/1 75.02952       0      2
11  3 2019/10/1 76.41390       0      3
12  3  2020/1/1 75.79827       0      3
13  3  2020/4/1 74.46035       0      3
```

I've tried my best searching for similar answers on internet but I couldn't come up with anything remotely close to what I want to do. I could only make it to the grouping part with

```
  group_by(ID)%>%
  mutate(Fulfill==if time-...)
```

and then stuck the "calculating difference with every other row" thing.  I'm imagining something like a loop for each row within a group(ID) to calculate the difference in time and then a logical statement for determining whether it's true or not. I've used R for a while but only with descriptive statistics previously, so I'm sorry if it's actually quite simple. Thanks.

Comment: nothing is simple with complex operations of R datasets ^^ You can decompose each step in a simple operation, and translate it into tiny code lines to update your question: 1) iterate through every ID with a for loop (equivalently an apply family function). 2) get the ID date and compute the limits of the time window. 3) re-iterate over all IDs but the one selected and select those inside this window 4) select the individual that has the most measurements.

Comment: for example, if you can get R understand that you're working with dates and time, you could write something like `lapply(X=df$Time, fun=function(date){return c(date-15months, date+1month)}` to return the time window (your question is not super clear concerning time criterion though, please clarify :) You may also want to read [this tutorial on R date and times](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~s133/dates.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach (not completely optimised, you could probably even simplify it to only one function call with `map_dfr` or so).

I've chosen to use `purrr::map_` functions. This allows me to apply the function to every entry of the column/vector separately (this results from the first time `Time` is passed to `map_`) and at the same time also pass the complete `Time` column (the second argument), to calculate the filter operations to see if you have entries in the +-15 months.

```r
ID=c("1","1","1","1","1","1","2","2","2","2","3","3","3")
Time=c("2015/1/1","2015/3/1","2016/1/1","2016/3/1","2017/1/1","2018/5/1","2012/1/1","2017/5/1","2019/4/1","2020/4/1","2019/10/1","2020/1/1","2020/4/1")
BW=rnorm(13,mean=75)
df<-data.frame(ID,Time,BW)

library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)

check_entries <- function(curr_entry, entries) {
  # establish bounds in which there must be entries
  lower_bound_1 <- curr_entry %m-% months(15)
  lower_bound_2 <- curr_entry %m-% months(9)
  upper_bound_1 <- curr_entry %m+% months(9)
  upper_bound_2 <- curr_entry %m+% months(15)
  
  # filter the entries that match the time period constraints
  entries <- data.frame(entries = entries)
  filtered_lower <- entries %>% 
    filter(entries >= lower_bound_1 & entries <= lower_bound_2)
  filtered_upper <- entries %>% 
    filter(entries >= upper_bound_1 & entries <= upper_bound_2)
  
  # check if there is a matching earlier and later entry
  if (nrow(filtered_lower) > 0 && nrow(filtered_upper) > 0) {
    TRUE
  } else {
    FALSE
  }
}

calculate_number_entries <- function(curr_entry, entries) {
  # establish bounds in which there must be entries
  lower_bound <- curr_entry %m-% months(15)
  upper_bound <- curr_entry %m+% months(15)
  
  # filter the matching entries and calculate the number of observations
  entries <- data.frame(entries = entries)
  entries %>% 
    filter(entries >= lower_bound & entries <= upper_bound) %>% 
    nrow()
}

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(Time = as.Date(Time, format = "%Y/%m/%d"),
    Fulfill = map_lgl(Time, check_entries, Time),
    Fulfill_ID = sum(Fulfill) > 0,
    Counts = map_int(Time, calculate_number_entries, Time))
#> # A tibble: 13 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID [3]
#>    ID    Time          BW Fulfill Fulfill_ID Counts
#>    <chr> <date>     <dbl> <lgl>   <lgl>       <int>
#>  1 1     2015-01-01  75.4 FALSE   TRUE            4
#>  2 1     2015-03-01  74.0 FALSE   TRUE            4
#>  3 1     2016-01-01  74.2 TRUE    TRUE            5
#>  4 1     2016-03-01  74.9 TRUE    TRUE            5
#>  5 1     2017-01-01  75.6 FALSE   TRUE            3
#>  6 1     2018-05-01  73.8 FALSE   TRUE            1
#>  7 2     2012-01-01  75.6 FALSE   FALSE           1
#>  8 2     2017-05-01  75.0 FALSE   FALSE           1
#>  9 2     2019-04-01  74.3 FALSE   FALSE           2
#> 10 2     2020-04-01  74.9 FALSE   FALSE           2
#> 11 3     2019-10-01  75.5 FALSE   FALSE           3
#> 12 3     2020-01-01  75.3 FALSE   FALSE           3
#> 13 3     2020-04-01  76.0 FALSE   FALSE           3
```

<sup>Created on 2020-12-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Note that I find a different result for the 5th entry, you may check if the month addition/subtraction is as you need it, check out [lubridate](https://lubridate.tidyverse.org/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for replying so late, your answer really helped a lot!

Comment: Glad to help! If the answer is useful for you, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thanks